# Как правильно посторить запрос MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=541 or (title LIKE '%blabla%') LIMIT 10`
Сейчас запрос выбирает `(id=541)` или `(title LIKE '%blabla%')`, но как сохранить приоритетность?

Нужно вытащить все данные из таблицы, где в приоритете `(id=541)`, а дальше нужно выбрать второй приоритетности данные, где
`(title LIKE '%blabla%')`.

В связи с присутствием лимита - данные `(id=541)` и вовсе можно не получить.

Comment: `ORDER BY {приоритетное выражение} DESC`. И вообще LIMIT без сортировки не имеет смысла, ибо лотерея.

Comment: ORDER BY не работает в данном случае, так как данные WHERE (title LIKE '%blabla%') могут быть больше или меньше 541,так что тут тоже лотерея 50/50

Comment: Извините, но всё, что Вы говорите, звучит как сплошной бред. Наверное, мы как-то по=разному думаем, что ли... попробуйте показать на примере (LIMIT 2 для демонстрации будет достаточно), исходные данные и требуемый результат.

Comment: Я наверное не совсем правильно выразился. ваша схема запроса работает, но при этом идёт сортировка, которую не нужно делать. Данные должны выбираться в хаотичном порядке, вплоть до ORDER BY RAND(); Тут важна именно приоритетность, то есть выбрать сначала, где id = 541 а остальное рандомом. Полагаю общий запрос должен состоять из подзапросов, но как это точно реализовать - я не знаю.

Comment: Хотите приоритетов - сортировка обязательна. Надо рандом - запихните запрос с сортировкой и лимитом в подзапрос, а снаружи уже примените ORDER BY RAND().

Comment: можете показать пример?

Comment: мне кажется все же Akina имел в виду что-то такое https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w9cuj11LjutP6adwELRqJK/1 про приоритетное выражение в сортировке

Comment: достаточно `order by (id <> 541)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то впервую очередь в результат должна попасть запись с `id=541` (если она есть), а затем записи `title LIKE '%blabla%'`. Почему бы в этом случае не использовать UNION?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=541 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id!=541 AND title LIKE '%blabla%' LIMIT 10
```

А ежели нужно ограничить количество до ровно 10:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=541 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE title LIKE '%blabla%'
) AS Temp LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @valextt это костыль

Comment: @teran - важно, что рабочий костыль :)

Comment: @valextt не важно. вам в комментах к самому вопросу намекали на нормальное решение. ссылка на фиддл там тоже есть.

Comment: Нет тут никаких костылей. Если не указан ORDER то MySQL гарантированно вернет первую запись `id=541` из результата объединения, а вот все остальные в той последовательности, в которой найдет (фатически неопределенной).

Comment: костыль это в принципе пихать сюда union

Comment: Как бы в этом и заключалась суть вопроса (как правильно сформировать запрос исходя из условий), union подошёл как нельзя кстати

Comment: @teran а как сделать без UNION, чтобы в результате одна часть была сортированной (id=541), а остальная часть несортированной (title LIKE '%blabla%'). Оформите ответ, мне самому интересно (честно).

Comment: @NoSkill комменты к вопросу почитайте

Comment: Так я почитал, и вроде как там все это можно сделать не менее чем двумя запросами. Тогда в чем преимущество, перед UNION? Оформите ответ, пожалуйста, если вы настаиваите, что это костыль.

Comment: @NoSkill до конца почитали? `order by (id <> 541)` - это все что  надо добавить к запросу, никаких юнионов

Comment: Напишите полный запрос, пожалуйста, который выводит в точности такой результат.

Comment: *Почему бы в этом случае не использовать UNION?* Потому что автор вполне явно и вменяемо заявил, что "при этом идёт сортировка, которую не нужно делать. Данные должны выбираться в хаотичном порядке, вплоть до ORDER BY RAND();". Если бы был UNION ALL - ответ гарантированно бы не соответствовал этому требованию. В случае же UNION DISTINCT определённый шанс на абы рандом сохраняется, ибо фиг знает, как именно сервер станет проверять на дублирование, вернее, какую именно сортировку он для этого учинит. Но что сортировка всё одно будет - это сто процентов.

Comment: @teran в вашем случае с использованием `order by (id <> 541)` нельзя сделать рандомную сортировку `WHERE title LIKE '%blabla%'`, а в случае с запросом @NoSkill можно применить рандомную сортировку, взяв подзапросы в скобки и добавив order by rand()

Comment: `order by (id <> 541),rand()`

Comment: @splash58 а вот это интересно, не знал, что так можно сделать!